# Error: "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 when trying to install unirest

I got this error after running the command `pip install unirest` to use the unirest in my `views.py`.
I am trying to use the api of petrol price in my project in which run this command

```
(geo) ABHISHEKs-MacBook-Air:map abksharma$ pip install unirest
Collecting unirest
 Using cached 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/da/2149cbd7a8c78f8b76b377379c1bda64ec36cc13315d55f6f7de6d094ac5/Unirest-1.1.7.tar.gz
Collecting poster>=0.8.1 (from unirest)
Using cached
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/dc/0683a458d21c3d561ab2f71b4fcdd812bf04e55c54e560b0854cea95610e/poster-0.8.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/84/0bcm7b0s6kx3496xf5ply6wh0000gn/T/pip-install-vf9ffv_s/poster/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import poster
  File "/private/var/folders/84/0bcm7b0s6kx3496xf5ply6wh0000gn/T/pip-install-vf9ffv_s/poster/poster/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import poster.streaminghttp
  File "/private/var/folders/84/0bcm7b0s6kx3496xf5ply6wh0000gn/T/pip-install-vf9ffv_s/poster/poster/streaminghttp.py", line 61
    print "send:", repr(value)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/private/var/folders/84/0bcm7b0s6kx3496xf5ply6wh0000gn/T/pip- 
install-vf9ffv_s/poster/
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import unirest


def petrol(request):

    response = unirest.post("https://fuelprice.p.mashape.com/",
    headers={
    "X-Mashape-Key": "eqPyWAd3Wrmsh52b6fvG3AQ5T2ygp1KZhDfjsng702Sd7DmWN7",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
  },
    params=("{\"fuel\":\"p\",\"state\":\"dl\"}")
)

    price = response.json()
    return render(request, 'petrol/petrol.html', {'price':price})
```

> url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views


urlpatterns = [
      path('', views.petrol, name='petrol')
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unirest is not supported in python3(atleast not in python 3.7). Instead of this, consider using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Use it like this:

```
response = requests.post("https://fuelprice.p.mashape.com/",
    headers={
    "X-Mashape-Key": "eqPyWAd3Wrmsh52b6fvG3AQ5T2ygp1KZhDfjsng702Sd7DmWN7",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
  },
    data={'fuel': 'p', 'state': 'dl'}
)

price = response.json()
```

Comment: after runing the server i got an error
 

JSONDecodeError at /Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: you can try with `response.text`, and `response.status_code` to see response body and status code. Its possible the response you are getting is not in Json serialize. Please see here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ for more usage of `requests`